# Bash Completion: Ubuntu vs CentOS

Tags: bash, ubuntu, centos

CentOS:

```
curl -Sso ~/Des[TAB]
```

autocompletes to:

```
curl -Sso ~/Desktop/
```

Ubuntu:

```
curl -Sso ~/Des[TAB]
```

does NOTHING.

I can "fix" this by uninstalling bash-completion, but that's not a real fix.

How do I get sane behavior out of bash-completion under Ubuntu 12.10?

Comment: 2nd google match https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acroread/+bug/769866 - you can start searching from there

Comment: I don't believe that is related to my problem.  My shell escapes characters such as spaces while auto-completing just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Uncomment the following section in /etc/bash.bashrc:

```
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```